# Getting file pid in mac-app-sandbox

Tags: python, macos, sandbox, psutil

I have an pyobjc Application for the Mac that I want to publish on in the app store. I order to get it published I need to put in a sandbox. One of the critical parts of the app is to watch the process id of the files that are opened. The files are opened using subprocess module and I am getting the pid using psutils. However, this does not work in the sandbox mode. Is there any alternate solution that I could use?

Comment: in cocoa you would use NSRunningApplication currentApplication processIdentifier. What will you do with the PID?

Comment: The functionality is similar to that of dropbox or box. The users open different files using the app, and I need a callback when the user closes it so that I can upload it to my web application.

Comment: What you describe is that closing a file in any app so I suggest to use Filesystem Events as described in FSEvents.h